# Como puedo poner las tablas verticalmente? HTML5

Tags: html, css3, tablas

Como puedo poner las tablas verticalmente? HTML5
Holaa la ayuda que ocupo es que no se como hacer que las 3 tablas me queden de forma horizontal como en la segunda imagen, adjunto fotos para que quede mas clara mi duda como también el código por cualquier duda, gracias de antemano.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Así me queda a mi
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y ocupo que me queden así

Y este es el código

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Laboratorio</title>
    <style>
        body {
            background-color: white;
        }
        table{
            border: 1px solid black;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 20px;
        }
        th{
            border: 1px solid black;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 20px;
        }
        td{
            border: 1px solid black;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 20px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th style="background-color: rgba(191,191,191,255);">Paises</th>
            <th style="background-color: rgba(191,191,191,255);">Medallas</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>USA</td>
            <td>13</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>China</td>
            <td>25</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>España</td>
            <td>6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Francia</td>
            <td>3</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" style="background-color: lightblue;">A</td>
            <td style="background-color: rgb(236,212,100);">B</td>
            <td style="background-color: rgb(171,206,142);">C</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="3" style="background-color: rgba(174,170,169,255);">D</td>
            <td colspan="2" style="background-color: rgba(237,125,49,255);">E</td>
            <td style="background-color: rgba(67,112,206,255);">F</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="background-color: rgba(112,173,70,255);">G</td>
            <td colspan="2" style="background-color: rgba(201,201,201,255);">H</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="background-color: rgba(46,116,182,255);">I</td>
            <td style="background-color: rgba(194,89,19,255);">J</td>
            <td style="background-color: rgba(191,143,0,255);">K</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" rowspan="2" style="background-color: rgba(189,215,238,255);">A</td>
            <td style="background-color: rgb(236,212,100);">B</td>
            <td style="background-color: rgb(171,206,142);">C</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" style="background-color: rgba(68,115,197,255);">D</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4" style="background-color: rgba(112,173,70,255);">E</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="background-color: rgba(174,170,169,255);">F</td>
            <td style="background-color: rgba(47,116,179,255);">G</td>
            <td colspan="2" style="background-color: rgba(197,89,17,255);">H</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Gracias por las respuestas hasta el momento aquí esta el código ojala me pueda ayudar que me tiene pegado esa duda y supongo que es sencillo porque es pasarlas de que estén vertical a que estén horizontal. Por cierto el código lo estoy trabajando en visual studio code.

Comment: Puedes aplicar la propiedad `display:block` a cada tabla. En todo caso edita tu pregunta y coloca el código que genera las tablas no las imágenes.

Comment: Añade el código que estás usando para ver cómo podría quedar.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que hice fue encerrar a todas tus tablas dentro de un `div` con una clase llamada `.contenido`, a esta clase le apliqué la siguiente propiedad:

```
.contenido {
  display: flex;
}
```

Luego, para tener un mejor resultado, le apliqué la propiedad `margin` a tus tablas para que tengan una separación en los lados:

```
table {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 10px; /* le damos separación a los 4 lados */
}
```

Tu resultado final, sería así:

```css
body {
  background-color: white;
}
table {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 10px;
}
th {
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
}
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
}

.contenido {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="contenido">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th style="background-color: rgba(191,191,191,255);">Paises</th>
      <th style="background-color: rgba(191,191,191,255);">Medallas</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>USA</td>
      <td>13</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>China</td>
      <td>25</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>España</td>
      <td>6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Francia</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" style="background-color: lightblue;">A</td>
      <td style="background-color: rgb(236,212,100);">B</td>
      <td style="background-color: rgb(171,206,142);">C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="3" style="background-color: rgba(174,170,169,255);">
        D
      </td>
      <td colspan="2" style="background-color: rgba(237,125,49,255);">E</td>
      <td style="background-color: rgba(67,112,206,255);">F</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="background-color: rgba(112,173,70,255);">G</td>
      <td colspan="2" style="background-color: rgba(201,201,201,255);">
        H
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="background-color: rgba(46,116,182,255);">I</td>
      <td style="background-color: rgba(194,89,19,255);">J</td>
      <td style="background-color: rgba(191,143,0,255);">K</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td
        colspan="2"
        rowspan="2"
        style="background-color: rgba(189,215,238,255);"
      >
        A
      </td>
      <td style="background-color: rgb(236,212,100);">B</td>
      <td style="background-color: rgb(171,206,142);">C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" style="background-color: rgba(68,115,197,255);">D</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="4" style="background-color: rgba(112,173,70,255);">E</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="background-color: rgba(174,170,169,255);">F</td>
      <td style="background-color: rgba(47,116,179,255);">G</td>
      <td colspan="2" style="background-color: rgba(197,89,17,255);">H</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Bro sos un crack me ayudaste demasiado, le sabe al html jaja Muchas Gracias

Comment: Un gusto poder ayudarle, saludos.